# React Native Flatlist multiple columns inside main column

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Please refer for the image
http://65.1.208.69/mahesh/rn.png

Please refer to below code, i have flatlist with in 2 function

1. renderAssetDetailsTableHeader for table columns.
2. renderAssetDetailsCell for data

```
<ScrollView
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}
    horizontal={true}>

    {this.renderAssetDetailsTableHeader({}, -1)}

    <View style={[styles.deviderHeaderHorizantal]} />

    <FlatList
        data={diselRequisitionDetails}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ index, item }) => {
            return (
                this.renderAssetDetailsCell(item, index)
            )
        }}
    />
</ScrollView>
```

```
renderAssetDetailsTableHeader(item, index) {
    var color = index % 2 == 0 ? '#edf9ff' : '#ffffff'
    color == index == -1 ? '#ffffff' : color
    var textColor = '#1777C7'
    return (
        <View style={[styles.cellContainder, { backgroundColor: color, height: 50 }]}>
            <SMLText
                style={[styles.cellText1, { width: 630 }]}
                text={'Diesel For Super Engine Working'}
                textColor={textColor}
                fontType='bold'
                fontSize={14} >
                <View style={[styles.deviderCell]} />
                <SMLText
                    style={[styles.cellText2, { width: 150 }]}
                    text={'Current Super Engine HMR'}
                    textColor={textColor}
                    fontType='bold'
                    fontSize={14} />
                <View style={[styles.deviderCell]} />
                <SMLText
                    style={[styles.cellText2, { width: 150 }]}
                    text={'Estimate Super Eng Working'}
                    textColor={textColor}
                    fontType='bold'
                    fontSize={14} />
                <View style={[styles.deviderCell]} />
                <SMLText
                    style={[styles.cellText2, { width: 150 }]}
                    text={'Diesel Working Qty'}
                    textColor={textColor}
                    fontType='bold'
                    fontSize={14} />
                <View style={[styles.deviderCell]} />
                <SMLText
                    style={[styles.cellText2, { width: 150 }]}
                    text={'Amount Required'}
                    textColor={textColor}
                    fontType='bold'
                    fontSize={14} />
                <View style={[styles.deviderCell]} />
            </SMLText>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: post your code so we can help.

Comment: Also your link is not accessible

Comment: @Guku Please check code now

Comment: @UgurEren Link is accessible now please check help me as soon as possible

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Can you format your code properly

Comment: @UgurEren Please refer image ,
want to do same in react native using flatlist

Comment: @Joshua Please check now

Comment: What you need is a grid system, check out some [here](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react%20native%20grid)